# What is the most efficient way to ask other turtle who can see the caller turtle in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I was wondering if anyone has a good idea to filter turtles who have the caller turtle in their vision and in their cone of vision with the least computational cost?

Now I am using something like this:

```
Member? Caller-Agent agents in-cone 5  100
```

or just who are agents who can see me? 
I was wondering if anyone knows how can I check if heading of other agents in some radius X is toward the caller agent ?

Comment: I was wondering what you've tried ?

Comment: The version that I am using has a high computational cost since it checks every present agents vision

Comment: See my advice on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113396/how-can-i-improve-following-function-in-netlogo . Have you tried using `distance` and `towards`? If you show your best effort at that, I and others here can critique it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , this is the way I did it:

I used abs( towards myself - heading) < 50

I thought it might include cone with angle of 100 since it uses absolute value.

This is just a test program to see if it works:

```
ask turtles[set label "" set color green]
ask turtle 7 [ 
set color red
set label "Caller"

ask other (turtles with [distance myself <= 3 and abs( towards myself - heading) < 50 ])
[

set color yellow
]

ask other turtles [

set label (Member? turtle 7 Other turtles  in-cone 3  100)
]
]
```

[image: Cone 100]

and this one cone 80 and abs( towards myself - heading) < 40 :
[image]

There is a problem with this approach:
if an agent is as same location of the caller then I will get the error that there is no heading defined to same point or something like that!

Error is : No heading is defined from a point (7,7) to that same point. error while turtle 28 running TOWARDS

***Update:***

```
[(distance myself <= 3 and distance myself > 0 and abs(  subtract-headings towards myself   heading ) < 60) or distance myself = 0 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I just used the set label (Member? turtle 7 Other turtles in-cone 3 100) ] ]  for double checking :)

Comment: You should use `subtract-headings a b` instead of `a - b`, otherwise your code won't handle angles near 0 and 360 properly. For example, the headings 5 and 355 are 350 apart numerically, but as headings, are only 10 degrees apart. `subtract-headings` understands that.

Comment: To handle the case where the agent is the same location as the caller, add `distance myself = 0 or ...`

Comment: [(distance myself <= 3 and distance myself > 1 and abs(round( towards myself - heading)) < 60) or distance myself <= 1 ] I used this one and it worked too, but 0 is better :)

Comment: what's the `round` there supposed to be doing...?

Comment: oops , thats just a mistake, i Used rounds to set labels  :D that should not be there!